# How to randomly sample along a finite line while maintaining minimum distance?

Tags: c++, math, statistics

Another way to say it might be "How to randomly distribute a known number of points along a line and maintaining a minimum distance between them".

If I have a container of size *n* which I want to distribute along a finite line of length *L*, how can I do this randomly. The order that they are distributed isn't important, hence why my question title is "sample".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> samplePoints;

    int lineLength = 100;
    int numPoints = 20;
    int minDistance = 3;

    for(int i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i)
    {
        /* how do I distribute these points? */
    }

    for(const int p : samplePoints)
        std::cout << p << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

How do I complete the loop above?

Comment: Is there some reason std::uniform_int_distribution (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_int_distribution) won't work?

Comment: @andand I'm not sure how to then enforce the minimum distance

Comment: Something like this: use `set<pair<int, int>>` to store available segments of the line (initially it's `{{0, lineLength}}`). Then randomly choose segment (with probability of it's length, let chosen segment be `{a, b}`) and point in it (let it be `x`), then split `{a, b}` into `{a, x - minDistance}` and `{x + minDistance, b}`. It seems that complexity of such solution can be improved by using treap.

Comment: @J.S this worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have n points to scatter over a total length L, with a minimum distance d between adjacent points.

So scatter them over a total length L-(n-1)d. Then iterate over them in order of increasing x, from P<sub>0</sub> to P<sub>n-1</sub>, moving each point P<sub>k</sub> a distance kd to the right.

Comment: How does this prevent points from extending outside the bounds of the range?

Comment: @andand, all the points are moved to the right for a distance `kd`, where `k` is `n-1` at most. Initially points scattered over a length `L-(n-1)d`, so `L-(n-1)d + (n-1)d` is `L`.